# How can we find a new file search in WebStorm?

Tags: eclipse, webstorm

In eclipse we can find a new file through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Is there any command to find a new file in WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Control+Shift+N
```

you can search a file in WebStrom